# how to structure code to run the same service for multiple objects?

Tags: c#

I have a number of instances of the following object:

```
public class Brief{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public DateTime StartDate {get; set;}
   public DateTime EndDate {get; set;}
}
```

I want to run the same console service for all these instances. the service essentially uses the ID property and the dates property to search in a database and return the related records for that particular Bried ID.

my question is what is the best approach to structure my code.

should I create a single class with a List and do a foreach on that list and run the appropriate method or should I create a different instance for each of the objects and then run the services.

Comment: I'd use a [Parallel.Foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx) over a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with List. Iterate over each one and fire off the method to do your search in a separate thread. That way all 3 searches are performing at the same time.